# Problems with nesting multiple h tags in one class

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with my CSS markup, I want multiple h tags to have the same property in one `class`, I thought it was correct to write:

```
.text-right h1, h2, h3 {
    text-align:right;
}
```

I.E, I want `h1`, `h2`, `h3` to be nested in `.text-right`, so when the parent container has the class `text-right`, any h tag in it will be right aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
.text-right h1, .text-right h2, .text-right h3 {
    text-align:right;
}
```